# CoffeeScript from CDN above 1.4.0 cannot call JavaScript function

Tags: coffeescript, cdn

CoffeeScript code is not working when the 1.10.0 version coffee-script.min.js is linked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <meta charset='utf-8'> </head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">Content</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<!--
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.4.0/coffee-script.min.js" > </script>
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.10.0/coffee-script.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/coffeescript" >
$("#myDiv").text "New Content"
alert "Hello world"
</script>
</html>
```

The latest **working** CDN coffee-script.min.js is **1.4.0**. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those script hosted in CDN are not for browser, I think.
I tried your code, and as you say it did not work and there was the following console log.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

`require` is a specification of commonJS and it is not implemented in browser default.

If you would not like to compile and make it work easily, the code below is available.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv">Content</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  $("#myDiv").text "New Content"
  alert "Hello world"
</script>

</html>
```

This way is introduced at the official site.
http://coffeescript.org/

> While it's not recommended for serious use, CoffeeScripts may be included directly within the browser using  tags. The source includes a compressed and minified version of the compiler (Download current version here, 39k when gzipped) as extras/coffee-script.js. Include this file on a page with inline CoffeeScript tags, and it will compile and evaluate them in order.

Comment: That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Error in packaging on the part of the CDN provider, see here:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3811

https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/4869